# "use" command failing with syntax error in PostgreSQL (converting from MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

So, I am trying to convert a MySQL-based database to a PostgreSQL database, and I'm getting some less-than-desirable results.  My code begins with this:

```
create database bookmarks;
use bookmarks;
```

But I get an error message that reads:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "use"
LINE 2: use bookmarks;
        ^
```

I am honestly at a loss in regards to what I need to do to fix this.  Any help you can offer me would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this by hand with `psql`, or are you using some programming language to do it?

Comment: A database in MySQL is usually better mapped to a schema in Postgres. For what it's worth, databases in MySQL behave and work like schemas. MySQL simply didn't choose to call them such (although in some places schema and database are synonyms in MySQL - very confusing)

Comment: Please try to use more specific titles for questions where possible, btw. 'horse' is right, too; if you're switching databases, you may want to use schemas within one database and use `search_path` to swap between them.

Answer (score 6):

In PostgreSQL, you connect to the particular database you want to use when you initiate a connection to the server. How you need to do this depends entirely on what language / environment you're using.

If you're doing this by hand using the `psql` command-line tool, though, then `USE mydatabase;` in MySQL is equivalent to `\c mydatabase;` in PostgreSQL.

**Edit:** In PHP, if you want to create a new database and then connect to it, you'd do the following:

1. Connect to your server using an existing database - `template1` or `postgres` are common choices for this. Execute `CREATE DATABASE bookmarks;` using this connection.
2. Create a **new connection** to the database you just created, using `new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=bookmarks;user=myuser;password=mypassword");` (replace the DSN parameters with your particular values as needed, of course).

Now you're connected to the new database, and any queries you execute will be executed against `bookmarks`. No need to execute `USE bookmarks;` or anything else.

Comment: I'm actually implementing the database using PHP.  I'm attempting to do so through this line of code:

Comment: <?php

function db_connect()
{
   $result = new PDO("pgsql:dbname='bookmarks';host='localhost', 'bm_user', 'password'); 
   if (!$result)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
   else
     return $result;
}

?>